# Universal js for group of divs

Tags: javascript

I have really simple question for someone with js skill. I have elements with numbered ids like: pictureframe-0, pictureframe-1, pictureframe-3.... and I want to make universal js based on this below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {$("#pictureframe-0").hover(function() {
        $("#cover-0").slideDown(500);
    }, function() {
        $("#cover-0").slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

where "0" will variate. Thank you for solution.

I know, when I duplicate this script like 20x times with numbers 1-20 it works separetly: pictureframe-0 will activate cover-0, pictureframe-1 will activate cover-1 etc.

Code is like this:

```
        <div class="pictureframe">
                <div class="cover">this is cover</div>          
         </div>
```

Comment: Gonna need to see the HTML first.

Comment: It is simple one div over another see higher.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your selector. If you use a prefix attribute selector, you could select leaving the rest of the id as a wildcard:

```
$(document).ready(function() {$("[id^=pictureframe-]").hover(function() {
        $("#cover-" + this.id.slice(-1)).slideDown(500);
    }, function() {
        $("#cover-" + this.id.slice(-1)).slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

UPDATE: As I mentioned in the comments, yes, you could also do this using a `for` loop, though personally I prefer the first way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < $("[id^=pictureframe-]").length; i++) {
        $("#pictureframe-" + i).hover(function() {
            $("#cover-" + i).slideDown(500);
        }, function() {
            $("#cover-" + i).slideUp(500);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It makes me hover all "covers" at once.

Comment: The only caveat with this is that the selector will also match other ids such as `cover-up` and `pictureframe-thumbnail` etc.

Comment: For making divs number i used: "for (var i = 0; i < pctframe.length; i++)
    pctframe[i].id = 'pictureframe-' + i;" so i guess it will be like this, just dont know how.

Comment: ah, very true. If you want to coordinate the id of the element you're sliding up with the element being hovered over, you'll need to either use a for loop to begin with like you've said, or you can use `this` to access the element currently being hovered. I'll update my answer

Comment: Hmm head over to chat here, don't want an extended comments discussion. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141474/universal-js-for-group-of-divs